# Overfitting of Regression with Robust Variances?

Tags: r, regression, stata, overfitting

I performed regression with robust variances (after Stata 12.1 lnskew transformation). A question of overfitting has been raised.

To summarise what I did:

1. Comparison of disease B (disgrp=2) versus disease C (disgrp=3)
   patients with 45-54 dependent observations (FibrosisP, continuous variable) in each disease group. Each patient had observations taken from Regions P, Q and R and Walls X, Y and Z (i.e. 9 observations per patient).
2. lnskew0 transformation (natural log transformation with zero skew of
   resulting distribution) of FibrosisP to give lfibr.
3. Simple and then multiple regression with clustered robust variances/standard errors (clustered by patient and using independent categorical variables Disease, Wall and Region).

Note that Disease A is excluded from this analysis (and is not provided in data set below).

$$ multipleregression: lfibr \sim Disease + Wall + Region $$

I have copied the original Stata v12.1 log file below, which will hopefully tell the whole story.

```
. gen disgrp=.
(153 missing values generated)

. replace disgrp=1 if disease=="A"
(54 real changes made)

. replace disgrp=2 if disease=="B"
(54 real changes made)

. replace disgrp=3 if disease=="C"
(45 real changes made)

. lnskew0 lfibr= fibrosisp

       Transform |         k     [95% Conf. Interval]       Skewness
-----------------+--------------------------------------------------
  ln(fibrosis-k) |   .0116473      (not calculated)        -2.77e-08

    . gen region1=.
(153 missing values generated)

. replace region1=1 if region=="P"
(51 real changes made)

. replace region1=2 if region=="Q"
(51 real changes made)

. replace region1=3 if region=="R"
(51 real changes made)

. gen wall1=.
(153 missing values generated)

. replace wall1=1 if wall=="X"
(51 real changes made)

. replace wall1=2 if wall=="Y"
(51 real changes made)

. replace wall1=3 if wall=="Z"
(51 real changes made)

. **Comparing C with B**

. xi:regress lfibr disgrp if disgrp > 1  , cluster(pat)

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =      99
                                                       F(  1,    10) =   20.51
                                                       Prob > F      =  0.0011
                                                       R-squared     =  0.3884
                                                       Root MSE      =   .5833

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 11 clusters in patientid)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       lfibr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      disgrp |   .9241372    .204061     4.53   0.001     .4694609    1.378813
       _cons |  -4.667246   .4602243   -10.14   0.000    -5.692689   -3.641802
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xi:regress lfibr region1 if disgrp > 1  , cluster(pat)

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =      99
                                                       F(  1,    10) =    3.17
                                                       Prob > F      =  0.1055
                                                       R-squared     =  0.0068
                                                       Root MSE      =  .74333

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 11 clusters in patientid)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       lfibr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     region1 |   .0748154   .0420368     1.78   0.105    -.0188483    .1684792
       _cons |   -2.54854    .177876   -14.33   0.000    -2.944872   -2.152207
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xi:regress lfibr i.region1 if disgrp > 1  , cluster(pat)
i.region1         _Iregion1_1-3       (naturally coded; _Iregion1_1 omitted)

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =      99
                                                       F(  2,    10) =    5.59
                                                       Prob > F      =  0.0235
                                                       R-squared     =  0.0612
                                                       Root MSE      =  .72645

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 11 clusters in patientid)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       lfibr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 _Iregion1_2 |   .4400513   .1398977     3.15   0.010     .1283397    .7517628
 _Iregion1_3 |   .1496308   .0845103     1.77   0.107    -.0386698    .3379314
       _cons |   -2.59547   .1905071   -13.62   0.000    -3.019946   -2.170993
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xi:regress lfibr i.wall1 if disgrp > 1  , cluster(pat)
i.wall1           _Iwall1_1-3         (naturally coded; _Iwall1_1 omitted)

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =      99
                                                       F(  2,    10) =    6.17
                                                       Prob > F      =  0.0180
                                                       R-squared     =  0.0630
                                                       Root MSE      =  .72575

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 11 clusters in patientid)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       lfibr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   _Iwall1_2 |   .3285724   .1654396     1.99   0.075    -.0400499    .6971948
   _Iwall1_3 |   .4356131   .1305289     3.34   0.008     .1447766    .7264496
       _cons |  -2.653637   .1780801   -14.90   0.000    -3.050425    -2.25685
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xi3:regress lfibr disgrp*i.region1*i.wall1 if disgrp > 1 , cluster(pat)
i.region1         _Iregion1_1-3       (naturally coded; _Iregion1_1 omitted)
i.wall1           _Iwall1_1-3         (naturally coded; _Iwall1_1 omitted)

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =      99
                                                       F(  8,    10) =       .
                                                       Prob > F      =       .
                                                       R-squared     =  0.5401
                                                       Root MSE      =  .55355

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 11 clusters in patientid)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       lfibr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      disgrp |   .5419458   .4154947     1.30   0.221    -.3838342    1.467726
 _Iregion1_2 |  -.2963738   1.409317    -0.21   0.838    -3.436529    2.843781
 _Iregion1_3 |  -.2791626   1.335259    -0.21   0.839    -3.254304    2.695979
   _Iwall1_2 |  -1.039268     .97762    -1.06   0.313    -3.217541    1.139005
   _Iwall1_3 |  -.9227228   1.131622    -0.82   0.434    -3.444133    1.598687
    _IdiXre2 |    .305921   .5859783     0.52   0.613    -.9997201    1.611562
    _IdiXre3 |   .2146185   .5228838     0.41   0.690    -.9504393    1.379676
    _IdiXwa2 |   .5887627   .4158743     1.42   0.187    -.3378629    1.515388
    _IdiXwa3 |   .5677226   .5322211     1.07   0.311      -.61814    1.753585
   _Ire2Xwa2 |   .9560212   1.372943     0.70   0.502    -2.103087    4.015129
   _Ire2Xwa3 |   1.876106   1.632401     1.15   0.277    -1.761111    5.513323
   _Ire3Xwa2 |   .1403149   1.711091     0.08   0.936    -3.672233    3.952863
   _Ire3Xwa3 |   .5961959   1.627029     0.37   0.722     -3.02905    4.221442
_IdiXre2Xwa2 |  -.4387073   .5346165    -0.82   0.431    -1.629907    .7524925
_IdiXre2Xwa3 |  -.7328102   .7126107    -1.03   0.328    -2.320606    .8549855
_IdiXre3Xwa2 |  -.1024311   .6268405    -0.16   0.873    -1.499119    1.294257
_IdiXre3Xwa3 |  -.3174033   .6961228    -0.46   0.658    -1.868461    1.233655
       _cons |  -4.217918   .9792797    -4.31   0.002     -6.39989   -2.035947
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xi3:regress lfibr disgrp i.region1 i.wall1 if disgrp > 1 , cluster(pat)
i.region1         _Iregion1_1-3       (naturally coded; _Iregion1_1 omitted)
i.wall1           _Iwall1_1-3         (naturally coded; _Iwall1_1 omitted)

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =      99
                                                       F(  5,    10) =   10.60
                                                       Prob > F      =  0.0010
                                                       R-squared     =  0.5127
                                                       Root MSE      =  .53177

                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 11 clusters in patientid)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       lfibr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      disgrp |   .9241372   .2084032     4.43   0.001     .4597858    1.388488
 _Iregion1_2 |   .4400513   .1421362     3.10   0.011      .123352    .7567505
 _Iregion1_3 |   .1496308   .0858625     1.74   0.112    -.0416828    .3409444
   _Iwall1_2 |   .3285724   .1680868     1.95   0.079    -.0459482    .7030931
   _Iwall1_3 |   .4356131   .1326175     3.28   0.008     .1401229    .7311033
       _cons |  -5.118535   .4532473   -11.29   0.000    -6.128433   -4.108637
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

csv data:

```
"row","PatientID","Disease","Wall","Region","FibrosisP"
"1",1,"C","X","P",0.11574464021797
"2",1,"C","X","Q",0.06409239204845
"3",1,"C","X","R",0.05589004594181
"4",2,"C","X","P",0.08452786770152
"5",2,"C","X","Q",0.19765474370344
"6",2,"C","X","R",0.29491566808792
"7",3,"C","X","P",0.13849556170319
"8",3,"C","X","Q",0.21529108879539
"9",3,"C","X","R",0.23260346696877
"10",4,"C","X","P",0.03242538798989
"11",4,"C","X","Q",0.18213249953927
"12",4,"C","X","R",0.0464009382069
"13",17,"C","X","P",0.12925196186539
"14",17,"C","X","Q",0.16685146683109
"15",17,"C","X","R",0.16298253982187
"16",5,"B","X","P",0.06082167946576
"17",5,"B","X","Q",0.06179248715729
"18",5,"B","X","R",0.04635879285168
"19",6,"B","X","P",0.0512284261286
"20",6,"B","X","Q",0.05560175796177
"21",6,"B","X","R",0.05038057719884
"22",7,"B","X","P",0.03485909775192
"23",7,"B","X","Q",0.07526805988175
"24",7,"B","X","R",0.03989544438546
"25",8,"B","X","P",0.05069990522336
"26",8,"B","X","Q",0.11638788902232
"27",8,"B","X","R",0.23086071670409
"28",9,"B","X","P",0.12712370092246
"29",9,"B","X","Q",0.05070659692429
"30",9,"B","X","R",0.06183074530974
"31",10,"B","X","P",0.04509566111129
"32",10,"B","X","Q",0.09050081347533
"33",10,"B","X","R",0.05178363738579
"52",1,"C","Y","P",0.14421181658066
"53",1,"C","Y","Q",0.1299066509205
"54",1,"C","Y","R",0.14904819595697
"55",2,"C","Y","P",0.08801608368174
"56",2,"C","Y","Q",0.24864891863453
"57",2,"C","Y","R",0.15962998919524
"58",3,"C","Y","P",0.4272296674396
"59",3,"C","Y","Q",0.2593375589095
"60",3,"C","Y","R",0.26700346966879
"61",4,"C","Y","P",0.14002780500134
"62",4,"C","Y","Q",0.28346720806288
"63",4,"C","Y","R",0.19312813953225
"64",17,"C","Y","P",0.17668051188556
"65",17,"C","Y","Q",0.18609876357474
"66",17,"C","Y","R",0.26587590290484
"67",5,"B","Y","P",0.05356234036154
"68",5,"B","Y","Q",0.04731210983269
"69",5,"B","Y","R",0.04877515848359
"70",6,"B","Y","P",0.06240572241178
"71",6,"B","Y","Q",0.13301297541279
"72",6,"B","Y","R",0.17973855854636
"73",7,"B","Y","P",0.06463245380331
"74",7,"B","Y","Q",0.10244742460486
"75",7,"B","Y","R",0.0599854720435
"76",8,"B","Y","P",0.05824947941558
"77",8,"B","Y","Q",0.11926213239492
"78",8,"B","Y","R",0.04685947691071
"79",9,"B","Y","P",0.06752011460398
"80",9,"B","Y","Q",0.09542812038592
"81",9,"B","Y","R",0.08668150350578
"82",10,"B","Y","P",0.06486814661182
"83",10,"B","Y","Q",0.05854476138367
"84",10,"B","Y","R",0.04438863783229
"103",1,"C","Z","P",0.05133333746688
"104",1,"C","Z","Q",0.14821006659988
"105",1,"C","Z","R",0.08174176027544
"106",2,"C","Z","P",0.23884995419341
"107",2,"C","Z","Q",0.2099355433643
"108",2,"C","Z","R",0.13176723596276
"109",3,"C","Z","P",0.46479557484677
"110",3,"C","Z","Q",0.33304596595977
"111",3,"C","Z","R",0.29770388592371
"112",4,"C","Z","P",0.15308213537672
"113",4,"C","Z","Q",0.28081619128875
"114",4,"C","Z","R",0.24592983188039
"115",17,"C","Z","P",0.21312809357862
"116",17,"C","Z","Q",0.23336174725733
"117",17,"C","Z","R",0.22714195157817
"118",5,"B","Z","P",0.06818263568709
"119",5,"B","Z","Q",0.07257093444773
"120",5,"B","Z","R",0.08201262934886
"121",6,"B","Z","P",0.0644884733419
"122",6,"B","Z","Q",0.11937946452025
"123",6,"B","Z","R",0.07081608918845
"124",7,"B","Z","P",0.06720225949377
"125",7,"B","Z","Q",0.12509595330262
"126",7,"B","Z","R",0.06657357031905
"127",8,"B","Z","P",0.05878644062606
"128",8,"B","Z","Q",0.26638352132337
"129",8,"B","Z","R",0.06789933388591
"130",9,"B","Z","P",0.0908078338911
"131",9,"B","Z","Q",0.17670466924957
"132",9,"B","Z","R",0.10642489420997
"133",10,"B","Z","P",0.05107976253608
"134",10,"B","Z","Q",0.07242867177979
"135",10,"B","Z","R",0.05074329491013
```

My interpretation is that we have 99 observations for 3 categorical variables (2-3 categories each) in the regression analysis; Root MSE = 0.53177.

Is overfitting a valid concern here? If so, is there any way to address it?

A general answer would be helpful. Moreover, I'm trying to move to R (rather than Stata), so advice on replicating the analysis and/or addressing overfitting with R would be gratefully received.

ADDENDUM1:
I've partially worked out how to replicate analysis in R. Haven't yet replicated lnskew0, though https://rpubs.com/chrisbrunsdon/skewness looks similar.

```
p2.df <- read.table("data_above.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

library(foreign)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(DAAG)

options(digits = 8)  # for more exact comparison with Stata's output

#create ln FibrosisP (need to replicate lnskew0 from Stata - manual k entered here from Stata calculation)

p2.df$FibrosisPln <- log(p2.df$FibrosisP-0.0116473)

p1.df <- p2.df[c("PatientID", "DiseaseG", "WallG", "RegionG", "FibrosisPln")]

p1.df$DWR <- paste(p1.df$DiseaseG, p1.df$WallG, p1.df$RegionG)

p.df <- pdata.frame(p1.df, index = c("PatientID", "DWR"), drop.index = F, row.names = T)

# tools_reg.R from http://www.existencia.org/pro/?p=134
source("tools_reg.R")
mod <- lm(FibrosisPln~factor(DiseaseG)+factor(WallG)+factor(RegionG),data=p.df)
get.coef.clust(mod, p.df$PatientID) # identical to Stata output
```

ADDENDUM2:
I have performed 10-fold cross-validation with CVlm from R package DAAG. However, I am uncertain how to interpret the results. Does the presence of overlapping lines in the plot for all 10 folds suggest no overfitting is present?

```
library(foreign)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(DAAG)
CVlm(df=p.df, form.lm=mod, m=10, plotit = c("Observed","Residual"), main="Small symbols show cross-validation predicted values", legend.pos="topleft", printit=TRUE)
```

[image: CVlm plot]

```
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        -3.2703     0.1441  -22.70  < 2e-16 ***
factor(DiseaseG)C   0.9241     0.2084    4.43  2.5e-05 ***
factor(WallG)Y      0.3286     0.1681    1.95   0.0536 .  
factor(WallG)Z      0.4356     0.1326    3.28   0.0014 ** 
factor(RegionG)Q    0.4401     0.1421    3.10   0.0026 ** 
factor(RegionG)R    0.1496     0.0859    1.74   0.0847 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

ADDENDUM3:
After a lot of searching, the only explanation I could find online (which I presume is accurate) is given at http://rstatistics.net/regression-modelling/

> "The fitted lines of different colors are parallel and on-top of each other. Indicating a stable model direction and less influence of outliers."